# Deploying Meteor on Heroku - multi dyno setup

Tags: heroku, meteor, dyno

Couple of questions for folks:

1. Within our Meteor app we have a scheduled job / background process that runs which is pretty separate and removed from the core web experience.  We'd like to run this job on a separate dyno.  Anyone have experience cutting up the meteor app and having it run different places?  Is this even doable?
2. I believe this will involve doing some stuff in the Procfile - but am struggling to figure out what to do!
3. Also wondering about the "buildpack" - given the need for "sticky sessions" which one is the best to go with?  Horse?  Other?

I hope we are on target enough that these questions even make sense!!!!

- Tewks

same ask on Meteor forums - I'll cross reference any helpful comments
(https://forums.meteor.com/t/deploying-meteor-on-heroku/15675)

[image]

Comment: Continuing to dig in a bit... from Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model here they give an example of starting different executables from the proc file.  Can different .js be "started" in Meteor?  (added the image above...)

Comment: still working on answer... not sure this is the right one... but likely creating secondary apps running in their own environment and point at same mongo instance.